# FreeTextTable across two related tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have Client table and a Contact table.  A Client can have multiple contacts, contact table has a FK to a Client PK.

I need a FreeTextTable query so I can search by Client Name or Contact Name.

I've been trying to UNION FreeTextTable results from each table without much luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Soemthing like this should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client A
LEFT JOIN Contact B
ON A.ClientId = B.ClientId
WHERE A.ClientName LIKE '%somename%' OR B.ContactName LIKE '%somename%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any idea how to get that done with FreeTextTable?